Lookat tracking isn't working in a sequence event (ue4)
I'm currently working on a sequencer event that uses lookat tracking to focus on a little robot that floats around the main character. I'm trying to get the camera to turn and look at the character during a sequencer cutscene. Debugging shows that the code is running but nothing is happening.
It's worth noting that I'm trying to control a cine camera that wasn't created by the sequencer. The blueprint is able to access it just fine but the sequencer doesn't cut to it at all.
I initially had this code set up to a cine camera event but it didn't work so I changed it to a sequencer event and I'm having the same problem.
Any idea on how to fix this?
